# How do I link and transfer data from one page to another in reactjs? (Not using render bc it doesn't work for me)

Tags: reactjs, api

I need to transfer data from an API from one page to another, I've tried various different methods and this is what I currently have, but it doesn't work, obviously I have a button created as well - Any other ideas inside of reactjs?

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

const onClick = () => navigate(`/pageIGoTo/${variable.id}`);

Comment: You can put data in the browser localStorage before leaving page then recover it: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Hey, can you put more detail about what you want to achieve ? From what I guess you're using react-router, so if you want to get the dynamic params you need to use useParams in the other component https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params

Comment: Yeah sure, I basically have a table that has a bunch of data pulled from an API, and whenever you click on a link in that table it will bring you to that specific items page, and the data from that item should transfer over. Lmk if that doesn't really make sense bc it's a messy message lol

Answer (score 0):

One option that works well, and is easy to inplement, is to include a `ViewModel` object in the `Props` object when creating views. See [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/app/app.tsx#L284) for an example.

Use of shared objects within view models enables view 1 to update data and for view 2 to then have access to the same data immediately. Note that React may recreate views frequently, but this does not affect view models.

If you want view 2 to refresh immediately, then you will need an event based mechanism. Eg view 1 raises an event, view 2 receives it and updates its state. See the use of [these events](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/tree/master/spa/src/plumbing/events) in my app for an example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out when I'm back working on the project :)